# Unable to connect PostgreSQL to remote database using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I installed PostgreSQL on my local server (Ubuntu) with IP 192.168.1.10.  Now, I'm trying to access the database from my client machine (Ubuntu) with IP 192.168.1.11 with pgAdmin.

I know I have to make changes in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf to allow the client to connect.  Could you please guide me?

Comment: Do you get an error? if so, what error?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Though, add a line saying
"host   all     all 192.168.1.0/24 md5 " in data/pg_hba.conf

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What command you are executing to connect to database from different server? What you are thinking to change in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf?

Comment: With 10.1 + pgAdmin 4 under windows 8.1, I uninstalled everything (subdirectories in c:\program files\postgresql\ and c:\program files (x86)\postgresql\ contain the uninstallers) and deleted both directories. Restared. Then installed pgAdmin 4 stand-alone. It worked! No other suggestions worked in my case. But this is not practical, so I can't leave this as an answer.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It is actually a 3 step process to connect to a PostgreSQL server remotely through pgAdmin3.

> Note: I use Ubuntu 11.04 and PostgreSQL 8.4.

1. You have to make PostgreSQL listening for remote incoming TCP connections because the default settings allow to listen only for connections on the loopback interface. To be able to reach the server remotely you have to add the following line into the file `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf:`

   **listen_addresses = '*'**
2. PostgreSQL by default refuses all connections it receives from any remote address, you have to relax these rules by adding this line to `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf:`

   **host all all  0.0.0.0/0 md5**

   This is an access control rule that let anybody login in from any address if he can provide a valid password (the md5 keyword). You can use needed network/mask instead of 0.0.0.0/0 .
3. When you have applied these modifications to your configuration files you need to restart PostgreSQL server. Now it is possible to login to your server remotely, using the username and password.

Comment: To start PostgresSQL server in ubuntu `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop` and `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start`. I googled for this. So adding it here for people who don't know the command to restart the service

Comment: In RedHat `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: A small update. The above `0.0.0.0/0 md5` works only for IPv4.
In order to enable access for IPv6 add the following line as well:
`host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5`

Comment: And by now, you might have found, but still in case: `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status` to see the status of the service you started or stopped.

Comment: On Windows don't forget about FIREWALL, disable it or add rule for postgres

Answer (score 8):

If you're using PostgreSQL 8 or above, you may need to modify the `listen_addresses` setting in `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf`.

Try adding the line:

```
listen_addresses = *
```

which will tell PostgreSQL to listen for connections on all network interfaces.

If not explicitly set, this setting defaults to `localhost` which means it will only accept connections from the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

In linux terminal try this:

- `sudo service postgresql start` : to start the server
- `sudo service postgresql stop` : to stop thee server
- `sudo service postgresql status` : to check server status

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to change my prostgresql.conf file but, i did have to do the following based on my psql via command line was connecting and pgAdmin not connecting on RDS with AWS.

I did have my RDS set to Publicly Accessible. I made sure my ACL and security groups were wide open and still problem so, I did the following:
`sudo find . -name *.conf`
then `sudo nano ./data/pg_hba.conf`
then added to top of directives in pg_hba.conf file `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`
and pgAdmin automatically logged me in.

This also worked in pg_hba.conf file
`host all all md5` without any IP address and this also worked with my IP address `host all all <myip>/32 md5`

As a side note, my RDS was in my default VPC.  I had an identical RDS instance in my non-default VPC with identical security group, ACL and security group settings to my default VPC and I could not get it to work.  Not sure why but, that's for another day.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to PostgreSQL via SSH Tunneling

In the event that you don't want to open port 5432 to any traffic, or you don't want to configure PostgreSQL to listen to any remote traffic, you can use SSH Tunneling to make a remote connection to the PostgreSQL instance. Here's how:

1. Open PuTTY. If you already have a session set up to connect to the
   EC2 instance, load that, but don't connect to it just yet. If you
   don't have such a session, see this post.
2. Go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels
3. Enter 5433 in the Source Port field.
4. Enter 127.0.0.1:5432 in the Destination field.
5. Click the "Add" button.
6. Go back to Session, and save your session, then click "Open" to
   connect.
7. This opens a terminal window. Once you're connected, you can leave
   that alone.
8. Open pgAdmin and add a connection.
9. Enter localhost in the Host field and 5433  in the Port field.
   Specify a Name for the connection, and the username and password.
   Click OK when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For redhat linux

```
sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf
```

pgsql9 is the folder for the postgres version installed, might be different for others

changed 
listen_addresses = '*'
from
listen_addresses = ‘localhost’
and then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall. When you disable it, then you can connect. If you want/can't disable the firewall, add a rule for your remote connection.

Comment: Can you give more details about the rules to be added?