# Connect postgres and Python

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh

I have a database available on a remote host. When I use putty and SSH, I am able to access it. The database itself has no password. Only, the SSH connection has a password. But, when I try to connect to it using Python, it asks for password. I'm new to postgres and paramiko.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import psycopg2
import paramiko
import time
t = paramiko.Transport(('xxx.com', 22))
t.connect(username="xxx", password='xxx') 
c = paramiko.Channel(t)
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxx'")
curs = conn.cursor()
sql = "select * from xxx"
curs.execute(sql)
rows = curs.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Other method that I tried was:

```
import os, psycopg2
os.system("ssh xxx@xxx.com -fNL 5432:localhost:5432 -p 22")
while True:
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxx'")
        curs = conn.cursor()
        sql = "select * from xxx"
        curs.execute(sql)
        rows = curs.fetchall()
        print(rows)
    except:
        print "I am unable to connect to the database"
```

This gives me a 'Could not request local forwarding' error.

Is there some other way to go about this? 
I have a Windows 7 (x64) machine with Python 2.7. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote server with pgadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937615/connecting-to-remote-server-with-pgadmin)

Comment: It looks like you were able to connect by changing your port number.  Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937615/connecting-to-remote-server-with-pgadmin ?

Answer (score 1):

You should connect to the remote server and make port forwarding of remote PostgreSQL to a local port.

Without paramiko, it's something like this:

```
# start port forwarding
$ ssh -L PGSQL_LOCAL_PORT:localhost:PGSQL_REMOTE_PORT user@xxx.com
# in python
psycopg.connect("dbname='xxx' host='localhost' port='PGSQL_LOCAL_PORT'")
```

Here is an example of doing this with paramiko
https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/pkg/trunk/paramiko/demos/forward.py?rev=30

Note: Port forwarding is blocking operation. So, you have to start port forwarding in separate thread/process.

Comment: I have tried forwarding as well. But it didn't work. I'm not sure what mistake I am making. I've made changes to my question.

Comment: Strange. This works for me.
Have you tried with different local port? And you could check if remote port is correct. As I remember, default port for PostgreSQL is 5433.

    ssh -L 14141:localhost:5433 myuser@myserver
    #....
    psycopg2.connect("dbname='my' host='localhost' port='14141' user='myuser' password='*******")

Comment: It gives me a bind: Not owner and then could not forward error for any port. Sorry, this is my first time dealing with SSH. So I don't know much. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Phew! Was able to connect to ssh finally! But, for the database, I get a connection refused  error :(

Comment: You've got this error when connecting from psycopg2?

Comment: Yes, for the psycopg2.connect command. I don't have a database username or password. Is that why I get this error? What values should I fill in these fields?

Comment: When you create a database (in PostgreSQL), current user automatically becomes the owner of the database. Default user in PostgreSQL is postgres. You can create new user for your database (what I strongly recommend) or you can change postgres password.

You can take a look at this gist
https://gist.github.com/Alexx-G/e79e477a1d32cd768d3b