# Postgres pgAdmin III Access to Database Denied

Tags: database, postgresql, windows-server-2012, pgadmin

I get the following error when attempting to connect to the Postgres instance on my server.

*Access to database denied
The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::2d93:af94:879c:4fa%12", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off*

I have tried the three obvious solutions found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287067/unable-to-connect-postgresql-to-remote-database-using-pgadmin). Namely I attempted Syed Aslam solution found in that^ link.

I tested that I was restarting the service correctly by removing some config to break my local pgAdmin III connection. I have checked if my firewall was blocking the connection by temporarily turning it off.

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting this error?

Postgres 9.4.1 
pgadmin III version 1.20 
Windows Server 2012 (host)
Windows 7 (trying to connect from this to the host)

Comment: Did you added the right line to pg_hba.conf? Add, for example:  ::/0. From documentation:  ::/0 represents all IPv6. Take a look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Cheers, it makes a lot more sense with that documentation XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had an IPv4 as the IP address in my entry for the pg_hba.conf. After changing it to an IPv6 version like this:

IPv4 = 0.0.0.0/0
IPv6 = ::/0

It all worked as I would have expected. The comment from user_0 and the documentation found [HERE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) cleared it up for me.

Obviously the answer works in reverse if you're using an IPv6 when you should be using an IPv4.