# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL on remote server via Pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Azure recently. Have been trying to connect to PostgreSQL but the server refuses the connection. I checked and confirmed that it was online. I also tried changing the settings to trust on pg_hba.conf and I also edited the Postgresql.conf file to listen to all addresses. Furthermore, I checked my firewall settings on Windows and allowed Pgadmin 4 to go through. Despite following all the instructions in this question ([Unable to connect PostgreSQL to remote database using pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287067/unable-to-connect-postgresql-to-remote-database-using-pgadmin)), I was unable to connect. What should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that postgres server is installed on Ubuntu system and you are trying to connect it from your local system using pgAdmin4?

Answer (score 2):

I once had such issue with pgAdmin4 on win 10.  Here is the step I took to connect to my remote server

first enable port 5432 to pass through firewall in ubuntu:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Then edit your postgresql.conf file and add

**listen_addresses** = "*"

file can be found at /etc/postgresql//main/postgresql.conf

Proceed to edit pg_hba.conf and add

```
host   all   all  0.0.0.0/0   md5
```

Now stop the server using`/etc/init.d/postgresql stop`  and restart   `/etc/init.d/postgresql start`

You should be able to connect now.  However, you can allow pgAdmin4 to pass through the windows firewall

```
control panel > System and Security > Allow an app through windows firewall
```

You can also allow same app for any antivirus you've installed

**Note:**
If you still cannot connect, you can reset your postgres user's password **NOT** linux default user

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
# \password postgres
Enter new password
```

Then use this new password to connect your pgAdmin4 using

- postgres as Maintenance database
- postgres as username
- then new password

Hopefully, you should be able to connect

Answer (score 0):

Enable your postgresql server to start at boot

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

Start your postgresql server

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

verify your postgresql server is running:

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

Comment: Are there any commands for 14.04? These are Systemd commands and I am on Upstart.

Comment: Never mind. i got to check the status through other commands. The server is running. It is online.